# WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value when use GeoOperations class in spring data redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

hi I want used Redis as a GeoDatabase and this is my code in spring boot:

```
`@RedisHash(value = "DeviceData"/*,timeToLive=60l*/)
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DeviceDataOnline extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Builder.Default
    private DeviceHostType hostType=DeviceHostType.VEHICLE;
    @GeoIndexed
    Point location;
    private double alt;
    private double speed;
    @Min(0)
    @Max(360)
    private double direction;
    private Boolean validity;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime packetDate;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime recieveDate;
    private byte[] sensorData;
    private byte[] eventData;
    private Short numberOfsats;
    private Short dop;
    private double milage;
    public DeviceDataOnline()
    {
        this.hostType=DeviceHostType.VEHICLE;
    }
}`
```

and this my Geoperations config:

```
` @Bean
    GeoOperations<String, DeviceDataOnline> geoOperations(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        RedisTemplate<String,DeviceDataOnline> redisTemplate=new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        //redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setEnableDefaultSerializer(false);
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(DeviceDataOnline.class));
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        GeoOperations<String,DeviceDataOnline> geoOpt=redisTemplate.opsForGeo();
        return  geoOpt;
    }`
```

when i call this methode :

```
@
```

```
`Override
    public Flux<DeviceDataDto> getAllLiveMovableInBox(BoxDto box) {
        double height=box.getTopRight().getX()-box.getBottomLeft().getX();
        double width=box.getTopRight().getY()-box.getBottomLeft().getY();
        GeoReference.GeoCoordinateReference refrenc=new                   GeoReference.GeoCoordinateReference(box.getBottomLeft().getX(),box.getBottomLeft().getX());
        GeoResults<GeoLocation<DeviceDataOnline>> results= 
        geoOperations.search(key,refrenc,new BoundingBox(height,width,Metrics.KILOMETERS));
       return       Flux.fromIterable(results.getContent().stream().map(t>t.getContent().getName()).map(onlineMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }`
```

i get this error :  WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

i expect geoOperations.search method return a GeoResult which contain stream of DeviceDataOnline